# IIS, SQL Server & Umbraco

Tags: sql-server, iis, umbraco, umbraco7

I wonder if anyone can help me out, we have a Umbraco installation running:

- **OS:** Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Standard, v10.0.14393 Build 14393
- **SQL Server**: SQL Server 2016 Standard Edition, v13.0.1728.2
- **Umbraco**: v7.3.4

The server had a scheduled reboot this morning at 5 am, from then, we've can't get the application back online, every time we go to the site we get the following error:

> [Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation timed out]
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed before completion of the operation or the server is not responding.]
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +2442598
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +5766516
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +285
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +4162
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData() +58
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() +89
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption) +409
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest) +2031
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry) +911
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) +64
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) +240
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +41
>
>   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +12
>
>   StackExchange.Profiling.Data.ProfiledDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +68
>
>   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader() +14
>
>   Umbraco.Core.Persistence.<Query>d__7`1.MoveNext() +265

I can't see any updates have run and looked at the windows update logs there isn't anything there neither.

I've tried

- Restarting the server
- Restarting the application pool.
- Restarting IIS
- Increase timeout to 6000.

If anyone can shed any more light on this it would be great.

Comment: It seems that the application can't access the database. Could you connect to it through sql server management studio ?

Comment: Hello, yes I can connect fine through management studio without any errors. @CyrilDurand

Comment: I read again the stack trace and it seems that the application can connect to the database because the exception is thrown in `ExecuteReader`. You could use sql profiler to better understand what's happening with the command.

Comment: @CyrilDurand I can't see anything in the SQL Profiler, it looks like all traces are completing. I can see messages about the Examine.ExamineManager._RebuildIndex() +116 could this be anything?

Comment: most of events in sql profiler has a start and a stop event. Could you configure the trace to see "start" and "stop" event.

Comment: Rebuilding indexes could be a very long task if there is no maintenance plan. Where do you see that ? maybe you should rebuild indexes through management studio and create a maintenance plan to do that in a scheduled time

Comment: I don't think the indexes have ever been rebuilt... Should I do this through the Management Stuido?

Comment: There isn't a maintenance plan setup at the moment.

Comment: @CyrilDurand I've rebuilt the index but it still doesn't want to work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204754/discussion-between-webdevb-and-cyril-durand).

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the command timeout from the default of 30 seconds. It's a property of the DbCommand object.

See here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbcommand.commandtimeout?view=netframework-4.8

I'd suggest you change it to the value 0 (i.e. unlimited)